# How to find the combined expected value

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Say we have expected values:

$E(X) = E(Y) = 0.4$

And variance:

$V(X) = 2$  and  $V(Y) = 1$

and the correlation between X and Y is $\rho(X,Y) = 0.3$

How do I find the expected value and variance for

$U = X + Y$ and $W = 2Y$

And the correlation between $U$ and $W$?

I have tried to solved it this way it, but I think its wrong:

$E(X+Y) = 0.4 + 0.4 = 0.8$

Comment: Isn´t $\mathbb E(X+Y)=\mathbb E(X)+\mathbb E(Y)=\color{blue}{0.4}+\color{blue}{0.4}=0.8$?

Comment: Please give a reply. Otherwise we must assume that you´re not really interested in the question.

Comment: @callculus Respectfully, I don't think that a lack of a reply within 10 minutes (or even several hours) of a comment indicates a lack of interest in the question.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery This was not my intention. I just want to give an information to the new user. On the other hand it is not asking too much to answer the question of my first comment within 10 minutes. It is the job of the questioner to clarify the question in a reasonable time.
itd-h.

Comment: @callculus "On the other hand it is not asking too much to answer the question of my first comment within 10 minutes." I emphatically disagree. I think it's unreasonable to assume or demand that a person posting a question must clear their schedule to attend to the question immediately after it is posted; they may well have other things to do that are not StackExchange-related. (On the other hand, if clarification is not given within a day or so, then sure, that's bad.)

Comment: I apologize so much for late reply!  Yes 0,4 + 0,4 = 0,8 it is a mistake, but is the method correct?

Comment: @AaronMontgomery If you have other things to do you should not post a question. And please think with the people who are concernded with the question. They cannot wait over 2 hours for an answer. They probably have other things to do as well. Btw, my first comment was 7 minutes after the question has been posted.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$
\text{Cov}(U,W)=\text{Cov}(X+Y,2Y) = 4( \text{Cov}(X,Y) + \text{Var}(Y)) 
$$